# Find the average value of the function $f(x,y)=cos((y-x)/(y+x))$ on the trapezoidal region with vertices $(1,0),(2,0),(0,2), \text{ and } (0,1)$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

One of my homework problems was this:
Find the average value of the function $f(x,y)=\cos(\frac{y-x}{y+x})$ on the trapezoidal region with vertices (1,0),(2,0),(0,2), and (0,1).

After sketching the region, I set up the bounds to get the following expression, which, when solved, should give me the answer:
$$\frac{\int_0^1 \int_{-x+1}^{-x+2} \cos(\frac{y-x}{y+x}) \,dy\,dx + \int_1^2 \int_0^{-x+2} \cos(\frac{y-x}{y+x}) \,dy\,dx}{\int_0^1 \int_{-x+1}^{-x+2} 1 \,dy\,dx + \int_1^2 \int_0^{-x+2} 1 \,dy\,dx}$$
After working out the bottom integrals, I simplified the expression to:
$$\frac{\int_0^1 \int_{-x+1}^{-x+2} \cos(\frac{y-x}{y+x}) \,dy\,dx + \int_1^2 \int_0^{-x+2} \cos(\frac{y-x}{y+x}) \,dy\,dx}{\frac{3}{2}}$$
The issue is I do not know how to solve the integrals in the numerator. What is the antiderivative of $\cos(\frac{y-x}{y+x})$ where x is held constant? Any help on how to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. From [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: You should research change of variables and Jacobians.

Comment: Partial duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765151/coordinate-transformation-of-double-integral